# VBA excel increments

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Hi guys I'm making a simple game in excel and I just need the smiley face image to increment up as its an endless runner type game. I have it moving up once I press the play button but I want it to then continue moving itself. Any ideas ?

Here is the the code I have so far:

```
Sub Play()

'
'

 Play Macro

'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Smiley Face 1028")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -20.8333070866

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move it in a loop with some sort of timer. See this example

```
Sub Play()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim r As Double

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Smiley Face 1028")
    r = shp.Top

    Do
        r = shp.Top
        If r <= 1 Then Exit Do
        shp.IncrementTop -1
        Wait 0.5 '<~~ Wait for 30 seconds
    Loop

    MsgBox "Animation Over. :) !!!"
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Double)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```